# .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for Window Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-3.5, windows-server-2008-x64

Where can I find the stand-alone or .iso  file of .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for Window Server 2008 R2 64bit?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an ISO, but rather an [installer](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe) (230 Mb). I believe it includes both x64 and x86 versions.